# Does improving edits affect the editors incentive?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

Does improving an edit remove or reduce the incentive for the one doing the edit? I sometimes find a minor thing I would like to improve, but it is not so important in case it would reduce the incentive of the original editor.

I guess I could just approve and then edit it myself to make sure to preserve the incentive for the previous editor. But it gets kind of messy doing multiple edits.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, "Improve Edit" accepts the proposed edit, and then applies your (improved) edit immediately afterwards. That is, I think the proposer just sees that their edit was approved (although if they go back to the question, they would see *you* had edited most recently) and gets the +2 reputation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pjs36 said, improving an edit includes approving it, so the user who suggested the edit gets their 2 points.

If you see edits that can be improved, by all means do improve. Editors tend to have blind spots, especially around the title area. Much too often, an editor will fix math formatting in the question while leaving its title such as "Probability Stat Problem" untouched. Or even worse...

[image: example]

Comment: Relatedly: Do you know what happened to the check box "was helpful"? Or was this somewhere else then when improving suggested edits.

Comment: The UI of edit reviews was  revamped last year as a part of "quality initiative", https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/

Comment: Now I see; I forgot that there is not only "Improve Edit" yet also "Reject and Edit" (not only "Reject"), which allows to make the judgement on the proposed edit via the choice of the button.